# Get list of sheets from excel spreadsheet

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, oledb

I am trying to populate a text box with all of the sheets found in my selected excel spreadsheet using visual studio 2010 and C#. So far I am unsuccessful with this task. Can anyone explain to me how I can do this?

Here is something I've been trying:

```
int index = 0;

Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.NamedRange NamedRange1 = Sheets;
//Globals.Sheet1.Controls.AddNamedRange(
//Globals.Sheet1.Range["A1"], "NamedRange1");
//Sheet1.Names.Add("tada", Sheet1.Range("A1:A4");

foreach (Excel.Worksheet displayWorksheet in Globals.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets)
{
    NamedRange1.Offset[index, 0].Value2 = displayWorksheet.Name;
    index++;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What did you try? Post your code

Comment: int index = 0;

            Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.NamedRange NamedRange1 = Sheets;
                //Globals.Sheet1.Controls.AddNamedRange(
                //Globals.Sheet1.Range["A1"], "NamedRange1");
            //Sheet1.Names.Add("tada", Sheet1.Range("A1:A4");

            foreach (Excel.Worksheet displayWorksheet in Globals.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets)
            {
                NamedRange1.Offset[index, 0].Value2 = displayWorksheet.Name;
                index++;
            }

Comment: Move it in your question this is unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

This page has explained how to get list of all worksheets from workbook - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59dhz064.aspx If you still cannot work out it, would you please be more specific about the problem you meet.

Comment: Hi, when i use this code i get an error saying The name 'Globals' does not exist in the current context.. Can you help me with this error?